Is there a simple way to specify xvfb-run when using VSCode's debugging function?
I would like to debug E2E tests using playwright (python) in codespaces on github.
On Docker, I use "mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python:v1.45.0" image and the headless operation is successful.
Also, with "xvfb-run pytest --headed", running in headed mode has been completed.
I would now like to connect to this container with VSCode and debug it. Is there a simple way to specify xvfb-run when using VSCode's debugging function?
I looked at setting.json, but could not directly find anything about setting the command to run pytest-playwright.
